# Magnific Popup doesn't popup

Tags: javascript, html, magnific-popup

I am very new to js, css. I have been scratching my head why my code doesn't work as shown on website.

Here is the HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
                    delegate: 'a',
                    type: 'image',
                    tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
                    mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
                    gallery: {
                        enabled: true,
                        navigateByImgClick: true,
                        preload: [0,1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
                    },
                    image: {
                        tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
                        titleSrc: function(item) {
                            return item.el.attr('title') + '<small>by Marsel Van Oosten</small>';
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="popup-gallery">
    <a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8242/8558295633_f34a55c1c6_b.jpg" title="The Cleaner"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8242/8558295633_f34a55c1c6_s.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
    <a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8382/8558295631_0f56c1284f_b.jpg" title="Winter Dance"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8382/8558295631_0f56c1284f_s.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
    <a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8225/8558295635_b1c5ce2794_b.jpg" title="The Uninvited Guest"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8225/8558295635_b1c5ce2794_s.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
    <a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8383/8563475581_df05e9906d_b.jpg" title="Oh no, not again!"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8383/8563475581_df05e9906d_s.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
    <a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8235/8559402846_8b7f82e05d_b.jpg" title="Swan Lake"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8235/8559402846_8b7f82e05d_s.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
    <a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8235/8558295467_e89e95e05a_b.jpg" title="The Shake"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8235/8558295467_e89e95e05a_s.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
    <a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8378/8559402848_9fcd90d20b_b.jpg" title="Who's that, mommy?"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8378/8559402848_9fcd90d20b_s.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sbm7/1pu0hyb7/1/

Anybody can show me some light please?

Comment: seems work fine http://jsfiddle.net/1pu0hyb7/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your JS fiddle is missing the **jQuery** loading on the left hand side. It was also **missing the code to the external CSS** files :) The actual fiddle would be fine if you had it actually loading the jQuery library, and the external CSS files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/site-assets/all.min.css?v=0.9.9"> 
<script src="http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js?v=0.9.9"></script>
```

See below:

http://jsfiddle.net/benjih111/nka153r8/

:D It happens to the best of us!